# Filter table with Bootstrap "checkbox"-Buttons

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, filter

I have a table which I want to filter with bootstrap checkbox buttons. The table is filled out of an array. So for example I want only to show rows with `"model"=BMW 1er`. How do I have to connect the button and how do I have to do the filter script?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
        <br>
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox">BMW 1er</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox">BMW Active E</label>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox">BMW 1er Cabrio</label>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox">BMW X1</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox">MINI</label>
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox">MINI Clubman</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox">MINI Coupé</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox">MINI Cabrio</label>
        </div>
        <br>
    </head>

    <body>
<font size="1"> 
<br>
<table class="table table-condensed" border="1" id="usertable"></table>
</font>

        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <div class="alert alert-success"> <a href="#" class="alert-link">Die Übersicht zu Drive-Now München lädt... Bitte einen Moment Geduld!</a>

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function callJSON() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $.getJSON('./url.php', function(data) {
                            $("#usertable").empty();
                            var cars = data.rec.vehicles.vehicles;
                            //cars.sort(function(el1,el2){ return el1.model == el2.model ? 0 : (el1.model < el2.model ? -1 : 1); });
                            cars.sort(function(el1, el2) {
                                if (el1.model == el2.model) {
                                    if (el1.fuelState == el2.fuelState) {
                                        return 0;
                                    } else if (el1.fuelState < el2.fuelState) {
                                        return -1;
                                    } else {
                                        return 1;
                                    }
                                } else if (el1.model < el2.model) {
                                    return -1;
                                } else {
                                    return 1;
                                }
                            });
                            $.each(cars, function(key, data) {
                                var laenge = cars.length;
                                var vint = data.vin;
                                var positionA = new google.maps.LatLng(data.position.latitude, data.position.longitude);
                                var posiitonB = new google.maps.LatLng(48.1351253, 11.5819806);
                                var entfernung = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(positionA, posiitonB);
                                var entfernung1 = (entfernung / 1000);
                                var entfernung2 = entfernung1.toFixed(2);
                                var entfernung3 = entfernung2 + " Km";
                                console.log(entfernung2);
                                console.log(positionA);
                                console.log(posiitonB);
                                var coopers = "";
                                var tanken = "";
                                var drive = "MAN";
                                var fuelfarbe = "#01DF3A";
                                var prozent = "%";
                                var kosten = " 31 Cent/Min "
                                var tanksymbol = "glyphicon-tint";
                                var farbe = "success";
                                var flugbadge = "";
                                var mode = "&dirflg=w";
                                var kraftstoff = "BENZIN";
                                var ortbadge = "glyphicon-map-marker";
                                var entfernungsbadge = "glyphicon-resize-horizontal";
                                var krafts = " (" + data.fuelState + "%)";
                                var strasse = data.address;
                                var v = vint.substring(3, 7);
                                var pdf = vint.substring(10, 17);
                                var pdf1 = pdf + ".pdf";
                                console.log(pdf);
                                if (data.fuelType == "DDE") {
                                    kraftstoff = "DIESEL";
                                }
                                if (v == "SX31") {
                                    coopers = " S";
                                }
                                if (v == "SW71") {
                                    coopers = " SD";
                                }
                                if (data.model == "BMW ActiveE ") {
                                    tanksymbol = "glyphicon-flash";
                                    kraftstoff = "STROM";
                                }
                                if (data.model == "BMW X1 ") {
                                    kosten = " 34 Cent/Min ";
                                }
                                if (data.auto == "Y") {
                                    drive = "AUT";
                                }
                                if ((48.347910654607695 < data.position.latitude && data.position.latitude < 48.35988839686733) && (11.781678199768066 < data.position.longitude && data.position.longitude < 11.792492866516113)) {
                                    flugbadge = "<span class='badge'>+12€</span>";
                                    ortbadge = "glyphicon-plane";
                                }
                                if (data.fuelState <= 25) {
                                    tanken = "20 Freiminuten für Vollbetankung";
                                    farbe = "warning";
                                }
                                if (data.position.latitude == "0") {
                                    entfernung3 = "NaN";
                                    strasse = "Nicht lokalisierbar";
                                    farbe = "active";
                                }
                                $('#usertable').append(

                                function() {
                                    return "<tr class=" + farbe + ">" +
                                        "<td>" + data.model + coopers + "</td>" +
                                        "<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> " + data.carName + "</td>" +
                                    //"<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> "+dur+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>" + drive + "</td>" +
                                        "<td><span class='glyphicon " + tanksymbol + "'></span>" + kraftstoff + krafts + "</td>" +
                                        "<td>" + data.licensePlate + "</td>" +
                                        "<td><span class='glyphicon " + ortbadge + "'></span> " + strasse + "</td>" +
                                        "<td><span class='glyphicon " + entfernungsbadge + "'></span> " + entfernung3 + "</td>" +
                                        "<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-euro'></span>" + kosten + flugbadge + "</td>" +
                                        "<td>" + laenge + "</td>" +
                                        "<td><a href='https://de.drive-now.com/php/metropolis/vehicle_details?vin=" + data.vin + "'target='_blank'><button class='btn btn-success btn-xs' type='button'>Reservieren</button></a></td>" +
                                        "<td><a href='http://maps.google.de/maps?saddr=" + posiitonB + "&daddr=" + data.address + mode + "'target='_blank'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type='button'>Route</button></a></td>" +
                                        "<td><a href='http://www.bmwarchiv.de/vin/" + pdf1 + "'target='_blank'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' type='button'>Route</button></a></td>" +

                                    //"<td><img src='"+data.model+"1.png'/></td>"+
                                    "<tr>";
                                });
                            })
                        }).always(callJSON);
                    }, 2000);
                }
                $(callJSON);
            });
        </script>
        <script>
            (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
                i[r] = i[r] || function() {
                    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
                a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
                a.async = 1;
                a.src = g;
                m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
            })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-44913908-2', 'voltdrive.de');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you please narrow down your problem.?

Comment: I dont know how to filter the table with a checkbox button. If e.g. BMW 1er is checked i only want rows to be shown with model=BMW 1er.

Comment: You'll need to give it a try and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: whats unspecific? I would try if i had a approach :/